# AS3 Library symbol linkage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, symbols, linkage

I'm having an issue using a class I've created as the base class for library symbols:

I've created a class `AvSkin` which will act as the display for an instance of `AvChild`. It looks like this:

```
package avian.environment.skins
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    /**
     * @author Marty Wallace
     * @version 1.0.0
     */
    public class AvSkin extends DisplayObject
    {
        /**
         * Getters
         */
        public function get top():Number{ return y - height/2; }
        public function get left():Number{ return x - width/2; }
        public function get bottom():Number{ return y + height/2; }
        public function get right():Number{ return x + width/2; }
    }
}
```

Obviously doesn't do a lot, but the point is that I can add to it later on (ie a `render()` method).

Problem is, because this extends `DisplayObject` (so that I can make the skin a `TextField`, `SimpleButton`, `Shape`, etc) and not `MovieClip`, it throws this error if I set it as the base class for a library symbol:

> **5000:** The class
>   'avian.environment.skins.AvSkin' must
>   subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip'
>   since it is linked to a library symbol
>   of that type.

Is there a way around this? I **don't** want to do either of the following:

1. Make `AvSkin` extend `MovieClip`.
2. Create a class for my library symbol that extends `AvSkin`.

See [here for a detailed representation of what extends DisplayObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000143.html), which might help back the reasoning behind my question.

Comment: Hmm is it possible instead of NOT extending MovieClip, you wish to extend ALL of the common DisplayObject subclasses? Like... some sort of multiple inheritance?

Comment: I could create multiple types of skins ie AvMovieClipSkin, AvBitmapSkin etc, but I wouldn't be able to extend a common skin class and thus would have to repeat the above logic in each.

Comment: Actually, there is a way around it. If you use the "include" keyword in each of your derived classes, and point it to one common ActionScript file (basically a portion of a class rather than a whole declaration), you can have your code centralized in one place so updates and additional features are easy to add across all types.

Comment: That's a good idea, but seems like sloppy OOP to me.

Comment: Well sloppy OOP yes, but this is a specific situation where it can be beneficial. And it depends how frequently you would have to update or modify the code. I've had experience with it - and sure enough it's awful to debug when first starting, but once everything is stable it's quite great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library symbols have a given type, i.e. `MovieClip` or `Sprite` and so on. If you want to inherit from these, you have to use this as base class. There is no workaround for this, it's an OOP paradigm for languages which do not support multiple inheritance, which AS3 is. You can't extend something in the middle of an inheritance tree.

For your task you could have an `Interface`. But you have to implement this interface in all your derived classes. But the implementation logic could be out sourced in a static class to ensure maintainability.

```
interface IAvSkin 
{
    function get top():Number;
    function get left():Number;
    function get bottom():Number;
    function get right():Number;
}

public class AvSkin
{
    public static function getTop(obj:DisplayObject):Number
    {
        return obj.y - obj.height/2;
    }

    // and so on
}

public class AvSkinMovieClip extends MovieClip implements IAvSkin
{
    public function get top():Number{ return AvSkin.getTop(this); }
    // and so on
}

public class AvSkinMovieClip extends Sprite implements IAvSkin
{
    public function get top():Number{ return AvSkin.getTop(this); }
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Not a fan of the static namespace though.

Comment: You could also have a non static helper `new AvHelper(this).getTop()` but creation of objects for this task takes unnecessary memory and execution time.

Comment: You'd also have to redefine the getters/other methods in each of the classes implementing IAvSkin which isn't appealing.

Comment: This answer is looking pretty good now; I do have one question though: Is there an advantage (other than readability) to defining my getters within an interface rather than just recreating the methods in each of the classes that implement it (which you have to do pretty much anyway)?

Comment: If you are implementing the interface your are sure, these getters exists on an object. You can use the type `IAvSkin` instead of DisplayObject, Sprite or MovieClip in your code. You could cast an object to `IAvSkin` and if this cast is successful, you know there is the getter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

How about extending **Sprite**? That is one of the most barebones DisplayObject subclass that won't have most of the MovieClip functionalities.

Comment: What if the skin were to be a Bitmap, Shape or Video?

Comment: True! Wasn't sure you'd need those :(

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've added a link to the types of things that could be an AvSkin (everything under DisplayObject). Should have added that clarification to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using composition?
You can instantiate the AvSkin and send the class you want to extend into it:

```
package avian.environment.skins
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    /**
     * @author Marty Wallace
     * @version 1.0.0
     */
    public class AvSkin extends DisplayObject
    {
        protected var _component:DisplayObject;

        public function AvSkin(component:DisplayObject) {
            addChild(_component = component);
        }
        /**
         * Getters
         */
        public function get top():Number{ return y - height/2; }
        public function get left():Number{ return x - width/2; }
        public function get bottom():Number{ return y + height/2; }
        public function get right():Number{ return x + width/2; }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var skin:AvSkin = new AvSkin(new MyMovieClip());
```

Now you can superclass it as much as you'd like.

Comment: It looks like you're typecasting which doesn't need so much work in the class itself to begin with. This also won't solve my issue which is linking library symbols to use AvSkin as a base class. Thanks for giving it a go for me.

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to linkage directly with that class. If you're dragging items onto the stage using the Flash IDE this won't help, but if you're instantiating from code there's not that much difference wrapping it as a parameter.